# Refactor case/when using strings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, refactoring

I have a number of these in my controller:

```
def ups
  @ups ||= Shipper::Ups.new(
    ENV['UPS_ACCESS_KEY'],
    ENV['UPS_PASSWORD'],
    ENV['UPS_USERNAME'],
    ENV['UPS_ACCOUNT']
  )
end
```

And then I have this block that gets called:

```
def type(number, carrier)
  case carrier.slug
  when 'ups'
    number_details = ups.track(number)
  when 'fedex'
    number_details = fedex.track(number)
  when 'usps'
    number_details = usps.track(number)
  end

  return number_details
end
```

But seems I could refactor that quite a bit if I could take the `carrier.slug` and prepend it to the lines like `ups.track(number)`.

Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `send` to do this but before that we need to make sure that you have the right carrier slug

```
if %w[ups fedex usps].include?(carrier.slug)
  send(carrier.slug).track(number)
end
```